# Is placing JavaScript on my site subject to XSS injections or the like?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been reading about XSS Injections and such, like

```
<script>document.write('<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+'"target="_blank"title="Facebook"style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:2em;height:2em;box-shadow:0 0 0 .1em #fff inset,.1em .1em 0.31em rgba(0,0,0,.3);background:#3b5998;"><svg style="display:block;fill:#fff;height:44%;margin:28% auto;" viewBox="0 -256 864 1664"><path transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,-95,1280)" d="M 959,1524 V 1260 H 802 q -86,0 -116,-36 -30,-36 -30,-108 V 927 H 949 L 910,631 H 656 V -128 H 350 V 631 H 95 v 296 h 255 v 218 q 0,186 104,288.5 104,102.5 277,102.5 147,0 228,-12 z" /></svg></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+'&text='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'"target="_blank"title="Twitter"style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:2em;height:2em;box-shadow:0 0 0 .1em #fff inset,.1em .1em 0.31em rgba(0,0,0,.3);background:#1b95e0;"><svg style="display:block;fill:#fff;height:36%;margin:32% auto;" viewBox="0 -256 1576 1280"><path transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,-44,1024)" d="m 1620,1128 q -67,-98 -162,-167 1,-14 1,-42 0,-130 -38,-259.5 Q 1383,530 1305.5,411 1228,292 1121,200.5 1014,109 863,54.5 712,0 540,0 269,0 44,145 q 35,-4 78,-4 225,0 401,138 -105,2 -188,64.5 -83,62.5 -114,159.5 33,-5 61,-5 43,0 85,11 Q 255,532 181.5,620.5 108,709 108,826 v 4 q 68,-38 146,-41 -66,44 -105,115 -39,71 -39,154 0,88 44,163 Q 275,1072 448.5,982.5 622,893 820,883 q -8,38 -8,74 0,134 94.5,228.5 94.5,94.5 228.5,94.5 140,0 236,-102 109,21 205,78 -37,-115 -142,-178 93,10 186,50 z" /></svg></a>');</script>
```

This is a social media share button.

Am I correct in thinking that the "document.write" section of the string is safe to place within my HTML page?

Comment: As long as the string is not affected by user input, which here it isn't, you should be fine.

Comment: if its user affected then yes, if its something youre doing as the website creator then no

Comment: it is affected by user input. document.URL is the whole url, which can include any parameters in the url ?someUserInput=.... however encodeURIComponent will take care of encoding the url thus removing unsafe characters. It would be dangerous without encodeURIComponent

Comment: btw use rel="noopener noreferrer" whenever using target="_blank"

Comment: Nope - it isn't meant to go into an iframe - I took if from here: https://www.buttons.social